# CSS child selectors - confused by navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a navbar, using bootstrap.

I've overridden bootstrap's defaults to make the li items of the navbar display across the whole width of the navbar, not clustered on the left. But this styling is being carried down to the dropdown menus too. No matter how much I play with the < I can't make this styling not apply to the dropdowns. I'm a CSS beginner, so any help would be appreciated!

My HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile-nav">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="VDiff" src="wp-content/themes/vdiff/images/logo/vdiff-small.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobile-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Basics</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Trad</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Trad Basics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gear</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advanced Skills</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Big Wall</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Trad Basics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gear</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advanced Skills</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Alpine</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Trad Basics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gear</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advanced Skills</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    ul .nav  {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .nav li { 
        display:inline-block;
        width:25%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .nav li a {
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:10px;
        display:block;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It should be `ul.nav` or just `.nav`, not `ul .nav` since you don't have any `.nav` elements under `ul`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd failed to take that out immediately before copying the code after the last thing I'd tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can target the immediate children by using > for all elements.

```
    .nav > li { 
        display:inline-block;
        width:25%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .nav > li > a {
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:10px;
        display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the navbar `id="navbar_list"` and use `#navbar_list li` to style that specific `<ul>`

Comment: Do you mean to have the OP put this on the dropdown `ul`? In that case, it should be a class since he has multiple dropdowns and you can't use the same id more than once.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question, thought he was talking about other `<ul>`s on the page, not within the menu. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

change you CSS in order to get full width as follows

```
.navbar-nav {
   display:table;
   width:100%;
   margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
   float:none;
   display:table-cell;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I set it to 80% to allow for the brand logo on the left hand side, that doesn't collapse. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You could try using button groups. I am not sure exactly what it is you are seeing when you click the dropdown. But here is the resource, and using .btn-group gets the series to act collectively.